# How to install older version of mariadb galera cluster to match the running galera cluster versions?

Tags: apt, mariadb

I have following collected deb packages:

```
~/mariadb_deb_packages$ ll
total 18728
drwxrwxr-x 2 ciasto ciasto    4096 Nov 24 22:47 ./
drwxr-xr-x 7 ciasto ciasto    4096 Nov 24 22:44 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 ciasto ciasto  821668 Apr 28  2017 galera-3_25.3.20-1_arm64.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 ciasto ciasto    6320 Apr  2  2019 libaio1_0.3.110-5ubuntu0.1_arm64.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 ciasto ciasto 4965688 Oct 26 19:18 mariadb-client-10.1_1%3a10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_arm64.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 ciasto ciasto 4140088 Oct 26 19:18 mariadb-client-core-10.1_1%3a10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_arm64.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 ciasto ciasto   16068 Oct 26 19:18 mariadb-common_1%3a10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_all.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 ciasto ciasto 4535116 Oct 26 19:18 mariadb-server-10.1_1%3a10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_arm64.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 ciasto ciasto 4329988 Oct 26 19:18 mariadb-server-core-10.1_1%3a10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_arm64.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 ciasto ciasto   12904 Oct 26 19:18 mariadb-server_1%3a10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_all.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 ciasto ciasto  321936 Apr  4  2018 socat_1.7.3.2-2ubuntu2_arm64.deb
~/mariadb_deb_packages$ sudo dpkg -i mariadb-server_1%3a10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_all.deb 
(Reading database ... 49379 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mariadb-server_1%3a10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mariadb-server (1:10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) over (1:10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:
 mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-10.1 (>= 1:10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1); however:
  Package mariadb-server-10.1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server
~/mariadb_deb_packages$ sudo dpkg -i mariadb-server-core-10.1_1%3a10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_arm64.deb
dpkg: regarding mariadb-server-core-10.1_1%3a10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_arm64.deb containing mariadb-server-core-10.1:
 mariadb-server-core-10.1 breaks mysql-client-5.5
  mariadb-client-10.4 provides mysql-client-5.5 and is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive mariadb-server-core-10.1_1%3a10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_arm64.deb (--install):
 installing mariadb-server-core-10.1 would break mariadb-client-10.4, and
 deconfiguration is not permitted (--auto-deconfigure might help)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server-core-10.1_1%3a10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_arm64.deb
~/mariadb_deb_packages$ sudo dpkg -i mariadb-client-10.1_1%3a10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_arm64.deb
dpkg: regarding mariadb-client-10.1_1%3a10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_arm64.deb containing mariadb-client-10.1:
 mariadb-client-10.1 conflicts with mysql-client-core-5.5
  mariadb-client-core-10.4 provides mysql-client-core-5.5 and is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive mariadb-client-10.1_1%3a10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_arm64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing mariadb-client-10.1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-client-10.1_1%3a10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_arm64.deb
~/mariadb_deb_packages$ sudo dpkg -i mariadb-client-core-10.1_1%3a10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_arm64.deb
dpkg: regarding mariadb-client-core-10.1_1%3a10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_arm64.deb containing mariadb-client-core-10.1:
 mariadb-client-core-10.1 conflicts with mysql-client-5.5
  mariadb-client-10.4 provides mysql-client-5.5 and is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive mariadb-client-core-10.1_1%3a10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_arm64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing mariadb-client-core-10.1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-client-core-10.1_1%3a10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_arm64.deb
~/mariadb_deb_packages$ sudo apt purge mariadb-client-10.4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-client : Depends: mariadb-client-10.4 (>= 1:10.4.17+maria~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
 mariadb-client-core-10.4 : Depends: mariadb-common (>= 1:10.4.17+maria~bionic) but 1:10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
 mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.1 (>= 1:10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
~/mariadb_deb_packages$ sudo apt purge mariadb-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-client-core-10.4 : Depends: mariadb-common (>= 1:10.4.17+maria~bionic) but 1:10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
 mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.1 (>= 1:10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
~/mariadb_deb_packages$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  galera-4 mariadb-common mariadb-server mariadb-server-10.4 mariadb-server-core-10.4
Suggested packages:
  mailx mariadb-test tinyca
Recommended packages:
  libhtml-template-perl
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  galera-3
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  galera-4 mariadb-server-10.4 mariadb-server-core-10.4
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mariadb-common mariadb-server
2 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 3532 B/19.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 150 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
~/mariadb_deb_packages$ sudo apt remove mariadb-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmariadb3 : Depends: mariadb-common but it is not going to be installed
 mariadb-client-10.4 : Depends: mariadb-common but it is not going to be installed
 mariadb-client-core-10.4 : Depends: mariadb-common (>= 1:10.4.17+maria~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
 mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.1 (>= 1:10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have tried removing individual but throws error

```
~/mariadb_deb_packages$ sudo apt remove libmariadb3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmariadbclient18 : Depends: libmariadb3 (= 1:10.4.17+maria~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
 mariadb-client-core-10.4 : Depends: libmariadb3 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: mariadb-common (>= 1:10.4.17+maria~bionic) but 1:10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
 mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.1 (>= 1:10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
~/mariadb_deb_packages$ sudo apt remove libmariadbclient18
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-client-core-10.4 : Depends: mariadb-common (>= 1:10.4.17+maria~bionic) but 1:10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
 mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.1 (>= 1:10.1.47-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

can anyone please help me install maraidb galera cluster distrib 10.1.47 and its dependencies ?

Comment: I recommend asking about the actual problem you face. Attempting to maintain older package versions on your system is not a very good fix and is unsustainable in the long run. As you can see, you already have a broken package management system from trying to do so. It's generally better that you find a better way to solve your problem.

Comment: The running galera cluster is using a version of mariadb that cannot be upgraded so i am trying to downgrade this 3rd node

Comment: How do you know it cannot be upgraded? That sounds like a problem begging for a solution.